# Combine sources in a row of sessions

Tags: looker-studio

Using Google Analytics as a data source I have a few rows in my source dimension I would like to combine. Like fb, facebook, fbook, etc, into one session metric.

How can I achieve this?

[image: Screenshot of my setup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a calculated field to combine the rows you wish. There are different functions available for you to do this. REGEXP_MATCH will allow you to use Regex to match or you can use 'IN','=' etc. Example below.

```
CASE WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Source, '.*facebook.*') OR REGEXP_MATCH(Source, '.*fb.*') THEN 'Facebook'
WHEN Source IN ('google','adwords') THEN 'Google'
ELSE Source
END
```